# overlapping searchable select tags IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create two searchable dropdowns, one above the other.
I'm using jquery's ".searchable" attribute, and i get the known IE 6-8 bug, that the dropdowns overlap:
[image: overlapping]

I tried to change the z-index of both of them, and changed the  positioning to "position:absolute", but I think that something with the jquery screws it up.

```
 <select name="courseID" class="dropdownSearch" id="courseID" style="position:relative;z-index:100">
     <option>...</option>
</select>
 <select name="sessionDate" class="dropdownSearch" id="sessionDate" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1">
     <option>...</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
$(".dropdownsearch").searchable();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What searchable library is that? It's not a core part of jQuery. Maybe it's [this one](http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/)? Don't blame jQuery if it doesn't work, blame the library. (note it says on that link that it won't work in IE6)

Comment: I'm not sure... could it be jquery-ui? (http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: You tell me; you're the one using it in your site.

Comment: And no, as far as I know, jquery-ui doesn't include `searchable` either. I guess it's a third party lib, but you're going to have to tell us which one.